# What causes the domain to change in the URL if entered incorrectly?

Tags: domain, url

Over time, I've noticed if I've entered the wrong domain (.gov, .com, .net) in a URL, the site is redirected to the correct site instantaneously . For example, www.usps.gov --> www.usps.com. Is this the browser, the site itself or something else causing the redirect?

Comment: In your example they are exactly the same site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many mechanisms that can cause this to happen.  In this case it is the web server that is doing the redirect:

```
--2012-04-13 10:22:01--  http://www.usps.gov/
Resolving www.usps.gov... 56.0.36.150
Connecting to www.usps.gov|56.0.36.150|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.usps.com [following]
--2012-04-13 10:22:02--  http://www.usps.com/
Resolving www.usps.com... 184.84.25.188
Connecting to www.usps.com|184.84.25.188|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.usps.com/ [following]
--2012-04-13 10:22:03--  https://www.usps.com/
Connecting to www.usps.com|184.84.25.188|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Your browser makes a connection to the webserver at www.usps.gov, which replies with a `302 Moved Temporarily` error , which tells the browser that the site is now at www.usps.com.  Browsers are generally configured to automatically accept `302` type errors and go to the new site indicated.  In this case, the new site also issues a `302` error, and says to go to `https://www.usps.com`, the secure version of the site.

Note that if you are using firefox, you can get it to tell you when a site is attempting to redirect in `Advanced / General` options.  Then you can see the jumps for yourself.

For details on various methods, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection (.htaccess, html redirect, server-side scripting, 301, etc) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record (DNS redirect)

Comment: For details on various methods, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection (.htaccess, html redirect, server-side scripting, 301, etc) and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record (DNS redirect).

Comment: @MaQleod thanks for that, I have added this to the answer to make it more thorough (feel free to edit these in yourself rather than in comments if it increases the quality of the answer)